# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping on ! value

Tags: ios, swift

I am using swift 2.2.I have one tab bar view controller with child of 2 view controller with navigation bar.And i have one different view controller and in that i have one button.So by button click i need to navigate to my 2nd child view controller of my tab bar view controller.

////  Code here ///

```
    let barViewControllers = sender.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController

    let nav = barViewControllers.viewControllers![2] as! UINavigationController

    let destinationViewController = nav.topviewcontroller as! CartVC
```

now i got and now new crash that in this line.`let barViewControllers = sender.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController`..Unexp fatal option error

Comment: What is topviewcontroller? UINavigationController does not have any part in it called topviewcontroller which you are trying to access.

Comment: now i got and now new crash that in this line.` let barViewControllers = sender.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController`..Unexp fatal option error

Comment: @WMios PLEASE see my updated problem and error

Answer (score 1):

if you have only two view controllers it should be `barViewControllers.viewControllers[1]` not `[2]`

```
let nav = barViewControllers.viewControllers![1] as! UINavigationController
```

Comment: But the error is in this line `let destinationViewController = nav.topviewcontroller as! CartVC`  After change to `1` also same error in same line

Comment: it is because of `nav` definition

Comment: `nav` ?? din get you..I checked the spell too of nav ??.Bust getting same error

Comment: now i got and now new crash that in this line.`  let barViewControllers = sender.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController`..Unexp fatal option error